# Class 'org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter' not found - how to correct?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven-2, spring-mvc

Eclipse STS is reporting I have problem with my spring project.

It's a fresh project generated from the Spring Web MVC Project Template (File->New->Spring Template Project->Spring Web MVC ).

When I create the project it has no problems - it's only once I modify the pom (by adding the hibernate dependencies) that STS then picks up the spring problem.

Strangely if I revert the pom the problem remains.

Also I can run the project on a spring tc server and all works correctly.

Any ideas how I can satisfy this problem report?

> "Class
>   'org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter'
>   not found"
>
> mvc-config.xml /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring line
>   9 Spring Beans Problem

mvc-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

 <mvc:annotation-driven />      <!-- <= PROBLEMATIC LINE REPORTED BY STS -->

 <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.rosteredon</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring23</artifactId>
    <name>test23</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.slf4j.version>1.5.10</org.slf4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!--  Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  URL Rewrite -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

SpringSource Tool Suite 
Version: 2.3.3.M1
Build Id: 201005180035
OS: Windows Vista HP SP1

Comment: what does your pom look like?

Comment: it's the one generatated by the web mvc project template.  strange hey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only part of the Spring WEB 3.0.2 build.

You can see it yourself in SpringSource's repository:

http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/search?query=ResourceHttpMessageConverter

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=312454

The project generated files that required SpringFramework 3.0.3,
but the pom specifies SpringFramework 3.0.1, causing the error message

Class 'org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMe ssageConverter' not found.

I updated the pom.xml to

```
<org.springframework.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
```

which solved the problem.

Let maven do the copying - should not copy individual files yourself and break the pom.